# Illegal modifier for parameter ITEMS; only final is permitted

Tags: android, list, listview

i'm a new here.
I'm try to do a message list, with the content of Message 1, Message 2 & Message 3.
But code below shows error message.

```
static final String[] ITEMS = new String[] { "message 1", "message 2", "message 3" };
```

error message:

```
Illegal modifier for parameter ITEMS; only final is permitted
```

however in "ANOTHER PROJECT", i'm doing a fruit list, using code below.

```
static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Banana", "Coconut" };
```

and it works perfectly fine. Both codes look exactly the same, so i have no idea where the problems.

below is the complete codes for the message list.

```
package net.eg.itemlist;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class Main extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    static final String[] ITEMS = new String[] { "message 1", "message 2", "message 3" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, R.id.textview_id, ITEMS);
    setListAdapter(adapter);            


}
}
```

Comment: What Mene said. Move that line to outside of `onCreate(...)` although I don't know why you would want the array to be `static` anyway.

Comment: thanks. well, cause i'm new to this, so what i'm doing is just follow and reference from others example in internet. so far what i know regarding "static" is used to define a class.(pls correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: Using the `static` modifier for a data member such as your `ITEMS` array in normal Java, would mean that it could be accessed from the class which defines it even without creating an instance of the class. This isn't how you should use an Android `Activity` however as it isn't a 'normal' Java class so you should never use `static` data members (fields) or `static` methods in an `Activity` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `static` within a Method. Move the declaration up to the class-level or remove the `static`.

`static` means it is a value of the class itself rather than of an instance of the class. So if you create 100 instances of your class there is only one shared instance of this variable if you declare it `static`, however there would be 100 instances if you don't declare it `static`.

In Java this kind of variable is only allowed at class-level.

As a side note: In C++ (not sure about C) you could use it inside of methods/functions with a similar semantic: the memory of that variable will be the same each time you call the function/method and the initialization will only be done on the first call. But you cannot address the memory from outside the function/method, thus the variable will be "function/method-private".

Comment: thanks.. it is useful, however application is not respond while running in AVD.. do u have any idea?

Comment: Not sure what AVD is supposed to mean. But since this is a different problem now, you're better off creating a new question.

Comment: @Mene : AVD -> Android Virtual Device, in other word the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` declaration from the ITEMS string array.

Or you can keep it if ITEMS array is declared as a class property.